# How to get current logged in user details in Twitter using API

Tags: twitter, laravel-5

I'm using Socialite to login using twitter and using Abrahams' TwitterOauth to make API working. In laravel, I've set API Key information as:

```
'twitter' => [
        'client_id'        => '**************',
        'client_secret'    => '**************',
        'access_token'     => '***************',
        'access_token_key' => '***************',
        'redirect'         => '***********',
    ],
```

To connect to Twitter I've used:

```
public function getTwitterConnection()
    {
        $this->connection = new TwitterOAuth(Config::get('services.twitter.client_id'), Config::get('services.twitter.client_secret'), Config::get('services.twitter.access_token'), Config::get('services.twitter.access_token_key'));
    }
```

Using Socialite, I'm able to make users login via their credentials. But while I try to access:

```
public function getCurrentLoggedInUser() {
        $this->getTwitterConnection();
        return $this->connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
    }
```

I'm getting the information of developer's twitter account i.e. mine.
I think I'm not being able synchronize between Socialite and TwitterOauth. 
How can I fix this issue? Please suggest me the better way of getting the information of logged in user.

Answer (score 2):

*I know it's late. But here is the answer anyway.*

```
    'access_token'     => '***************',
    'access_token_key' => '***************',
```

You don't need to include these details. This `access_token` and `access_token_key` belongs to your own account and that's why you are getting your account information instead of the logged in user. You have to use `access_token` and `access_token_key` of the logged in user, so this shouldn't be prefilled by you.

Inside the controller which is handling twitter's callback redirect:

```
    // get logged in twitter user
    $user = Socialite::driver('twitter')->user();

    // OAuth One Providers
    $token = $user->token; // this is access_token that you need
    $tokenSecret = $user->tokenSecret; // this is the access_token_key that you need

    // now call TwitterOauth with all the details 
    // and then you can send request to account/verify_credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

These codes helped me a lot:

For Login:

```
public function redirectToTwitter() // AuthController.php
{
    $t = new Twitter();
    $t->sessionDestroy();
    return redirect($t->getAuthUrl());
}

public function handleTwitterCallback(Request $request)
{
    $t = new Twitter();
    $oauth = $request->all();
    $user = $t->getCurrentLoggedInUser($oauth);
}
```

For Verification: Twitter.php

```
public function getTwitterConnection(){
    $oauth_token = Session::get('oauth_token');
    $oauth_token_secret = Session::get('oauth_token_secret');
    if(!empty($oauth_token) && !empty($oauth_token_secret)) {
        $this->connection = new TwitterOAuth(Config::get('services.twitter.client_id'), Config::get('services.twitter.client_secret'), $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    }
    //return $this->connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
}

public function getAuthUrl() {
    $this->getAuthConnection();
    $token = $this->connection->oauth("oauth/request_token", array("oauth_callback" => Config::get('services.twitter.redirect')));
    Session::put($token);
    $url = $this->connection->url("oauth/authorize", ['oauth_token' => $token['oauth_token']]);
    return $url;
}

public function getCurrentLoggedInUser($oauth) {
    $this->getTwitterConnection(); //gets oauth for developers
    $access = $this->connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $oauth['oauth_verifier']));
    Session::put('oauth_token', $access['oauth_token']);
    Session::put('oauth_token_secret', $access['oauth_token_secret']);
    $this->getTwitterConnection(); //after login gets oauth for logged user
    return $this->connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for twitter with socialite 
use

```
$user = Socialite::driver('twitter')->userFromTokenAndSecret($token,$secret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm doing GitHub and Twitter oauth logins in a Laravel API + Vue SPA (that uses JWT stored in cookie). I will show my installation because it may contain some rare elements.

I already had the GitHub oauth redirect and callback working, so I just needed to add Twitter, which proved quite difficult. I solved it using the `abraham/twitteroauth` composer package. It's a nimble, minimal script.

```
/**
 * Redirect the user to the provider authentication page. Twitter uses OAuth1.0a, and does not support
 * Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless(), so library `abraham/twitteroauth` is used to handle everything.
 *
 * @param  string $provider
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    if ($provider === 'twitter') {
        $tempId = Str::random(40);

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(config('services.twitter.client_id'), config('services.twitter.client_secret'));
        $requestToken = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => config('services.twitter.callback_url').'?user='.$tempId));

        \Cache::put($tempId, $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'], 86400); // 86400 seconds = 1 day

        $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $requestToken['oauth_token']));
    } else {
        $url = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
    }

    return [
        'url' => $url,
    ];
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from the provider.
 *
 * @param  string $driver
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $provider)
{
    if ($provider === 'twitter') {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(config('services.twitter.client_id'), config('services.twitter.client_secret'), $request->oauth_token, \Cache::get($request->user));
        $access_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/access_token', ['oauth_verifier' => $request->oauth_verifier]);

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(config('services.twitter.client_id'), config('services.twitter.client_secret'), $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials', ['include_email' => 'true']);
        $user->token = $access_token['oauth_token']; // this is used in the findOrCreateUser and createUser function
    } else {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
    }
    $user = $this->findOrCreateUser($provider, $user);

    $this->guard()->setToken(
        $token = $this->guard()->login($user)
    );

    return view('oauth/callback', [
        'token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'expires_in' => $this->guard()->getPayload()->get('exp') - time(),
    ]);
}
```

If you look close, you'll see `\Cache::put()` and `\Cache::get()`. The purpose of that is to supply the Twitter access token to the `handleProviderCallback` method. Twitter attaches `'?user='.$tempId` to the callback request, so you can use `$request->user to find the temporary user ID of the access token.

Read the Laravel docs to learn more. The default .env variable `CACHE_DRIVER=file`, so Cache::put() will place a file somewhere.

The `'include_email' => 'true'` gem is how you instruct Twitter to include the user's email address, and this only works if you enable email address support in your Twitter app settings area. Doing that requires having a terms of service page and a privacy policy page.

I believe my Socialite installation is mostly normal; you can check out this example repo that I got everything from (note Laravel API + Vue SPA): https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa

**.env**

```
# localhost
GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=
GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=
GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL=https://something.test/api/oauth/github

TWITTER_CLIENT_ID=
TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET=
TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL=https://something.test/api/oauth/twitter/callback
```

Note: I created two GitHub applications and two Twitter applications: one for localhost, and one for production. The only difference is the domain. This will allow you to test the oauth logins locally.

**config/services.php**

```
    'github' => [
        'client_id' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'callback_url' => env('GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL'),
    ],

    'twitter' => [
        'client_id' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'callback_url' => env('TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL'),
    ],
```

Don't forget to update your `.env.example` file with those oauth key names.

Also don't forget to check that example repo because I added this Twitter stuff on top of that.